# AngularJS - scenario.js code

Tags: angularjs

In the application building tutorial on [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org), **step-8**, testing part, what does the following lines of code mean-

```
element.all(by.css('.phones li a')).first().click();
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe('/phones/nexus-s');
```

Thanks in advance!

PS:
The exact URL is- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08 and the code file *(scenarios.js)* is-

```
    'use strict';

// Angular E2E Testing Guide:
// https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

describe('PhoneCat Application', function() {

  describe('phoneList', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('index.html');
    });

    it('should filter the phone list as a user types into the search box', function() {
      var phoneList = element.all(by.repeater('phone in $ctrl.phones'));
      var query = element(by.model('$ctrl.query'));

      expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(20);

      query.sendKeys('nexus');
      expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(1);

      query.clear();
      query.sendKeys('motorola');
      expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(8);
    });

    it('should be possible to control phone order via the drop-down menu', function() {
      var queryField = element(by.model('$ctrl.query'));
      var orderSelect = element(by.model('$ctrl.orderProp'));
      var nameOption = orderSelect.element(by.css('option[value="name"]'));
      var phoneNameColumn = element.all(by.repeater('phone in $ctrl.phones').column('phone.name'));

      function getNames() {
        return phoneNameColumn.map(function(elem) {
          return elem.getText();
        });
      }

      queryField.sendKeys('tablet');   // Let's narrow the dataset to make the assertions shorter

      expect(getNames()).toEqual([
        'Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi',
        'MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122'
      ]);

      nameOption.click();

      expect(getNames()).toEqual([
        'MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122',
        'Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi'
      ]);
    });

    it('should render phone specific links', function() {
      var query = element(by.model('$ctrl.query'));
      query.sendKeys('nexus');

      element.all(by.css('.phones li a')).first().click();
      expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe('/phones/nexus-s');
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is testing of the routing to `/phones/nexus-s`.
It is written in [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/).

The first line reads the DOM and finds all the `.phones li a` css rules. It then takes only the first one and calls `click()` on it.

```
element.all(by.css('.phones li a')).first().click();
```

The second line expects the output of the function `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` to be the string `/phone/nexus-s`

```
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe('/phones/nexus-s');
```

So all in all the test framework clicks a button and expects it to be routed to a new page.

Comment: No problem @Trivedi. You can also "one up" the answer if you feel like it

Comment: Of course, but I'm falling 1 reputation short in doing so.
Maybe you can help me in that ;)